# Elementary OS нет звука нигде

Tags: sound

подскажите что делать использовал команду 
alsamixer
там ничего на mute не стоит но звука все равно нет, я новичок в Linux помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Do you speak english? Не очень много люди говорят по рускии сюда.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might want to try clicking in the "speaker" icon on the top bar of eOS and then click "Sound Settings".

Make sure your preferred and desired sound output is checked as you might have multiple outputs:
[image]